# (R) Conditionally Format Cells in Table

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, formatting, dashboard

I'm having 2 separate issues with my R Shiny dashboard I was hoping you all could help me with:

1.) I am trying to have a dynamic data table that allows the user to select a metric averaged by Group and Month and the table will automatically update based on the selection of the metric.  Right now, the table updates appropriately, but its outputting the wrong numbers.  Can someone take a look and see what is wrong with this?

2.) I am having some trouble using an example I found here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html to highlight cells in the table based on their values.

Here's a reproducible example of the data:

```
Group=c('A','B','B','A','C','A','C','A','B','B')
Date=c("2019-03-14","2019-03-21","2019-03-28","2019-04-04","2019-04-09",
   "2019-04-18","2019-05-02","2019-05-14","2019-05-23","2019-05-30")
Metric1=c(15,20,45,22,19,25,24,34,20,10)
Metric2=c(500, 510, 520, 540, 539, 645, 600, 585, 534, 589)
Metric3=c(100,110,120,130,140,140,150,155,155,167)

data=as.data.frame(cbind(Group, Date, Metric1, Metric2, Metric3))
```

Here is the code I am using to produce the dashboard:

```
#Load libraries
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)


#Manipulate data
data$YearMon=as.yearmon(data$Date)
Year_Month=unique(data$YearMon)
MetricChoices=c("Metric1", "Metric2","Metric3")


# Define UI for application 
 ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Data Analysis"),
    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title=""),
      dashboardSidebar(
         sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Metrics",
                   tabName = "heat_table",
                   icon=icon("calculator")
          ),
          selectInput(inputId = "metricselect",label="Select a Metric:",choices=MetricChoices)

        )
       ),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(

          tabItem(
             tabName = "heat_table",
            DTOutput("heat_table")
          )

        )
      )
     )
   )

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

    HighlightTableData=reactive({

     #Make the highlight table 

     subdata = data %>%
      select(Group,YearMon,input$metricselect)

     subdata=data.frame(subdata)
     subtable=as.data.frame(aggregate(x=as.numeric(subdata[,3]),
                                      by=list(as.factor(subdata[,1]),
                                              as.factor(subdata[,2])),
                                     FUN=mean))
     subtable$x=round(subtable$x,2)

     library(reshape)
     subtable2=as.matrix(reshape(subtable,direction="wide",
                                 v.names="x",
                                 timevar="Group.2",
                                 idvar="Group.1"))
     Year.Mon=as.character(unique(subtable$Group.2))
     colnames(subtable2)=c("Group",Year.Mon)
     return(subtable2)

  })
   output$heat_table=renderDT({

   # brks <- quantile(HighlightTableData()[-1], probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
   # clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
   # {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}

    datatable(HighlightTableData(),rownames=FALSE,
              options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                             lengthChange=FALSE,
                             dom = 't'))# %>%

     # formatStyle(Year_Month, backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
  })  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The lines commented out attempt to create a table with highlighted cells.  When uncommented, I get an error that reads, "non-numeric argument to binary operator."

Can someone help point me in the right direction?  I'm not sure how to solve these problems.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - had to chop off the first column of the table being created in the reactive chunk of code to match the columns being formatted in the renderDT section.  Then, switched rownames=FALSE to TRUE.

Here's the code:

```
 HighlightTableData=reactive({

  #Make the highlight table static first

  subdata = mydata %>%
    dplyr::select(Location,YearMon,input$metricselect)

  subdata=data.frame(subdata)
  subtable=as.data.frame(aggregate(x=subdata[,3],
                                 by=list(subdata[,1],
                                         subdata[,2]),
                                 FUN=mean))
  subtable$x=round(subtable$x,0)

  library(reshape)
  subtable2=as.data.frame(reshape(subtable,direction="wide",
                             v.names="x",
                             timevar="Group.2",
                             idvar="Group.1"))
  Year.Mon=as.character(unique(subtable$Group.2))
  colnames(subtable2)=c("Studio",Year.Mon)
  subtable3=subtable2[-1]
  rownames(subtable3)=c(unique(mydata$Location))
  return(subtable3)




 })

output$heat_table=renderDT({

   brks <- quantile(HighlightTableData(), probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
  clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
  {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}

  datatable(HighlightTableData(),rownames=TRUE,
            options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                           lengthChange=FALSE,
                           dom = 't')) %>%
 formatStyle(names(subtable3), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))

 })
```